# How to determine if the process is stationary or ARMA process?

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

Given process $X_t$, where $Z_t$ is iid N(0,1):$$X_t−\frac{1}{2}X_{t−1}−\frac{1}{2}X_{t−2}=Z_t−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t−1}−\frac{1}{4}Z_{t−2}$$

It is known that process $X_t$ is stationary if $E[X_t^2] < \infty , E[X_t] = \mu \text{ and } \gamma(t,t+h) = \gamma(h,0)$. How do I practically determine if it is stationary?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct equation?  Why the $-2$ on both sides?

Comment: Should that read: $\gamma(t,t+h) = \gamma(0,h)$? Also for clarity, can you explicitly specify what you mean by $\gamma$?

Comment: @Rahul It might be helpful to define it in the question, but generally $\gamma(n,m)$ denotes the covariance of $X_n$ and $X_m$, which is symmetric with respect to the indices, so in particular $\gamma(0,h) = \gamma(h,0)$

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminaries:** Consider $Z_t−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t−1}−\frac{1}{4}Z_{t−2}$. This has mean 0 as it is the sum of three $N(0,1)$ Random variables. The variance: $Var\left(Z_t−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t−1}−\frac{1}{4}Z_{t−2}\right)
=Var(Z_t)+\frac{1}{4}Var(Z_{t−1})+\frac{1}{16}Var(Z_{t−2})
=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}
=\frac{21}{16}$. Thus $Z_t−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t−1}−\frac{1}{4}Z_{t−2}\sim N(0,\frac{21}{16})$.

Therefore from the given equation we have for all $t$:
\begin{align*}
X_{t+2}−\frac{X_t+X_{t+1}}{2}&\sim N(0,\frac{21}{16})\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note: The covariance between $X_t$ and the normal variable on the RHS is not 0.

Claim: The process is stationary.

Proof: We need to show three things. (i) mean is constant (ii) variance is finite (iii) covariance depends only on time differences

We will prove these in order.

**(i) mean is constant:** We will prove this by induction. Assume mean is constant $\mu$ for all random variables up to $t+1$. Then from eq(1), we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [X_{t+2}−\frac{X_t+X_{t+1}}{2}]&= \mathbb E [N(0,\frac{21}{16})]\\
\mathbb E [X_{t+2}]−\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb E [X_t]+\mathbb E [X_{t+1}]\right]&= 0\\
\mathbb E [X_{t+2}]&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\mu+\mu\right]=\mu\\
\end{align*}

**(ii) variance is finite:** For this part, we will assume covariance depends only on time differences (which we will prove in the third part). From eq(1)
\begin{align*}
Var [X_{t+2}−\frac{X_t+X_{t+1}}{2}]&= Var [N(0,\frac{21}{16})]\\
Var [X_{t+2}]+\frac{1}{4}\left[Var [X_t]+Var[X_{t+1}]\right] - Cov(X_t,X_{t-1})- Cov(X_t,X_{t-2})+ \frac{1}{2}Cov(X_{t-1},X_{t-2})= \frac{21}{16}\\
\end{align*}
Using $\gamma$ notation in the question, and third property(yet to prove),
\begin{align*}
Var [X_{t+2}]+\frac{1}{4}\left[Var [X_t]+Var[X_{t+1}]\right] - \gamma(0,1)- \gamma(0,2)+ \frac{1}{2}\gamma(0,1) = \frac{21}{16}\\
Var [X_{t+2}]+\frac{1}{4}\left[Var [X_t]+Var[X_{t+1}]\right]= \frac{21}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma(0,1)+\gamma(0,2)\\
Var [X_{t+2}]+\frac{1}{4}\left[Var [X_t]+Var[X_{t+1}]\right]= c\\
\end{align*}
where c is some constant. Therefore $Var [X_{t+2}]\leq c\quad \forall t$

**(iii) covariance depends only on time differences:**
Fix some $X_t,X_{t+1}$, then we can derive closed form expressions for all $X_{t+i}\quad \forall i\geq 2$. For example,
\begin{align*}
X_{t+2} \sim Z_{t+2}−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t+1}−\frac{1}{4}Z_{t} + \frac{X_t + X_{t+1}}{2}\tag 2
\end{align*}
Substituting this value and again using eq(2) for $X_{t+3}$, we get
\begin{align*}
X_{t+3} &\sim Z_{t+3}−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t+2}−\frac{1}{4}Z_{t+1} + \frac{X_{t+2} + X_{t+1}}{2}\\
&\sim Z_{t+3}−\frac{1}{2}Z_{t+1}−\frac{1}{8}Z_{t} + \frac{3}{4}X_{t+1} + \frac{1}{4}X_{t}\\
\end{align*}
Similarly, $X_{t+4} \sim Z_{t+4} -0.375 Z_{t+1} - 0.125 Z_t + 0.625 X_{t+1} - 0.375 X_t$ and $X_{t+5} \sim Z_{t+5} -0.375 Z_{t+2} - 0.125 Z_{t+1} + 0.6875 X_{t+1} - 0.3125 X_t$

Similarly, we can derive expressions for every $X_{t+\tau}\quad \forall \tau\geq 2$ in terms of $X_t,X_{t+1}$ and some multiples of iid $N(0,1)$ random variables. Notice that the equations do not change, depending on what $t$ is. We may observe that here the expressions depend on both $X_t,X_{t+1}$, and ask whether they should not depend only on $X_t$.

To this we can answer that while the coefficients change, the sequence of coefficients of $X_{t+\tau}$ in terms of $X_{t+1},X_{t}$ converge. Specifically, they converge to $\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3}$ in this case. The coefficients of the normal random variables do not change (as seen in $\{X_{t+4},X_{t+5}\}$). Finally, we write, for large enough $\tau$, $X_{t+\tau} \sim Z_{t+\tau} - \frac{3Z_{t+\tau-3}}{8} - \frac {Z_{t+\tau-4}}{8} + \frac{2X_{t+1}}{3}+\frac{X_{t}}{3}$.

Now we can remove dependence on $X_{t+1}$ for large enough $t$. Starting at $t=0$, for large $\tau$, the expression doesn't change from $\tau$ to $\tau +1$. Thus, $X_{\tau+1}\sim X_{\tau}$. Therefore, starting at large enough $t$,
\begin{align*}
X_{t+\tau} &\sim Z_{t+\tau} - \frac{3Z_{t+\tau-3}}{8} - \frac {Z_{t+\tau-4}}{8} + \frac{2X_{t+1}}{3}+\frac{X_{t}}{3}\\
&\sim Z_{t+\tau} - \frac{3Z_{t+\tau-3}}{8} - \frac {Z_{t+\tau-4}}{8} + \frac{2X_{t}}{3}+\frac{X_{t}}{3}\\
&\sim Z_{t+\tau} - \frac{3Z_{t+\tau-3}}{8} - \frac {Z_{t+\tau-4}}{8} + X_t
\end{align*}

Therefore, after some initial states, the process is stationary.

Comment: Based on the condition given in the question, I would assume OP means [weakly] stationary, i.e. covariance stationary.

Comment: You seem to show that if it's stationary, then $\mu = 0$.  I have a sneaking suspicion that either OP wanted to assume this or they wanted to ignore the initial values by pushing them back beyond the indices we're considering.

Comment: @Rahul Madhavan Shouldn't $\mathbb{E}[Z_t - Z_{t-1}/2-Z_{t-2}/4] =0?$ Since $\mathbb{E}[Z_t - Z_{t-1}/2-Z_{t-2}/4] =\mathbb{E}[Z_t]- \mathbb{E}[{Z_{t-1}}]/2-\mathbb{E}[Z_{t-2}]/4 $ and since $Z_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, the expected value for $\mathbb{E}[Z_t] = \mathbb{E}[{Z_{t-1}}]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{t-2}] = 0?$ Did I miss something here?

Comment: @Fianra, thanks a lot. Corrected answer as per your comments.